# Angularjs <style> tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, media-queries

I am struggling with following understanding:
How can I add media (query) depending styles dynamically to elements/the DOM?

Following issues I ran into:

1) I know that AngularJS cannot manipulate tags like
`<style> {{myMediaQueryStyles}} </style>` in a directive.

2) Media queries injected as inline styles with `ng-style` doesn't work either

I have the following `view-model.json`

```
{
    "id":"936DA01F-9ABD-4D9D-80C7-02AF85C822A8",
    "contexts":[
        "@media (max-width: 1200px){ … }",
        "@media (max-width: 760px){ … }",
        "@media (max-width: 420px)){ … }"
    ]
}
```

In a simple directive I just try to write them into a `<style>` tag

```
app.directive('addStyles', function()
{
    return {   
        template: '<style>{{view-model.contexts}}</style>'        
    };
});
```

Is there any workaround to add media relevant styles dynamically to elements or the whole document in angularJS?

Changing the directive `template: '<div>{{view-model.contexts}}</div>'` works but the styles then just won't get applied.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are giving the style tag an array of strings. I think you need to change your contexts to just one big string rather than an array.

Comment: Thanks. Well, this was just an example. It doesn't work with `<style>{{view-model.contexts[0]}}</style>` either.

Comment: Do not dynamically update page style. It causes jank because browser would have to re-render entire page. Rethink your problem and solve it with on static CSS file and manipulating classes on your HTML elements in order to change their style or visibility.

Comment: as per @ZackArgyle comment...try `{{view-model.contexts.join('')}}`

Comment: @Mohsen Correct me if I am wrong, but sometimes you need to reflect dynamically changes that cannot be predicted by a class. And browser re-render is so marginal in my case, I can post performance test if you like.

Comment: @ZackArgyle Thanks. It doesn't work. I altered my viewmodel to `   "contexts":" /* Media query string */ "`. 
Still it doesn't render in the view.

Comment: Pretty sure Angular doesn't parse styles. Inspect the element and it will look like `<style type="text/css">{{view-model.contexts}}</style>` rather than `<style type="text/css">div { /*styles*/ }</style>`. Maybe try looking into the ng-style directive: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngStyle

Comment: @Chad Yes I know, that's why I am asking. I would have used ng-styles, but you cannot apply media query styles directly inline to the element. Otherwise I would already been using this, because it enables dynamic binding as well.
I am trying out another attempt by hooking into the `link` function of the directive and use my own createElement for the `style` node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround would be to add the relevant styles to the  element in a custom directive's `link` function, as shown in this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nSFBUZEQ81ClX1y759CD?p=preview).

In a simple case, in which the viewModel is made available directly in the controller, the directive would look like this:

```
app.directive('addStyles', function()
{
  return function(scope, el, attrs) {
    el.text(scope.viewModel.contexts.join('\n'));
  };
});
```

You could also load the JSON from a separate file or remote source (as shown in the Plunk) by tweaking the directive:

```
app.directive('addStyles', function($http)
{
  return function(scope, el, attrs) {
    $http.get('viewModel.json').then(function (result) {
      el.text(result.data.contexts.join('\n'));
    });
  };
});
```

This would allow for dynamically updating the styles. This is demonstrated in the Plunk by adding a $timeout to the directive that clears the styles after 3 seconds (you can see the text change from colored to black).

In either case, the relevant HTML markup would be `<style add-styles></style>`.

Comment: Awesome, I had a similar approach to this. But this definitively works. Thanks Sarah!